# Jquery or javascript auto click automatically

Tags: click, mouse

I need to Code auto mouse click automatically 
action after several seconds of entering the site without interference from me.

Comment: `$(someSelector).click();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume the element's id is btn. To trigger the click event after 2 seconds the code would be like:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input id='btn' onclick='alert("Auto Clicked")'/>

<script>
setTimeout(function(){
     document.getElementById('btn').click();
       },2000);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you 
But how can I use in HTML page ?

Comment: Updated the answer. wait two seconds and the alert will be shown.

Comment: Thank you very much Ahmed
But there is a problem and it's not working either on Firefox browser only

Comment: Hi Hossam I tested it in browsers : IE, Firefox, Chrome. And it works. Are you sure you are not doing something wrong?

Comment: no no you can tested it in this site http://t7mel-bramj.blogspot.com/ it's not working either on Firefox browser only

Comment: can you please post the button or whatever element in the question, is it bound to a form? The network here wont let me open the url you share.